# jQuery dynamically named variables

Tags: jquery, variables

I am working on a code, perhaps my approach is wrong working inside a "for" loop. Here is it:

```
for(var index = 0; index < $('div.parent').find('div.child').length; index++){
    var element[index] = $('div.parent').find('div.child').eq(index);
    // some code
}
```

The code should look like this:

```
for(var index = 0; index < $('div.parent').find('div.child').length; index++){
    var element1 = $('div.parent').find('div.child').eq(1);
    // some code with element1
    var element2 = $('div.parent').find('div.child').eq(2);
    // some code with element2   
}
```

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: What is your question or problem?  You posted two different pieces of code, both of which are very inefficient, that do different things.

Comment: Why are you trying to collect the elements like this though? The jQuery object is probably more useful.

Comment: I am not a coder I ask if it is possible. I don't know why you have to vote down for my question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't dynamically create a variable of a certain name. You will need to use an array:

```
var elements = [];
var children = $('div.parent').find('div.child');
for(var index = 0; index < children.length; index++){
    elements.push( children.eq(index) );
    // some code
}

//reference by:
elements[0];
elements[1];
// etc.
```

Or even simpler with jQuery:

```
var elements = $('div.parent').find('div.child').toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I hope you didn't vote down for my question, I am just not a coder and I hope this reply of yours could help others. I will give it a try.

Comment: No problem, it's a fair question if you don't have much experience. Give it a try and let me know if there's something you don't understand, glad to help.

Comment: That is so sweet. I mostly do some easy stuff, just learning about loops and stuff. So I am sure this would work, as always when you deal with such amazing people.

Comment: can I call for some element like this $(elements[1]).addClass('demo'); for instance? ( elements[1] is the second in array right? )... Thanks again.

Comment: Yep you can do `$(elements[1]).addClass('demo')`, and yes that does refer to the second element.

Comment: OK tested and works. After so much work I adapted into my code and it's very fine :). Thanks so much.